# primefaces component (P:layout) not working at all

Tags: jsf, layout, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm trying to use the example of PrimeFaces showcase 
[ElementLayout](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutHome.jsf)  but the layout is not diplayed at all !

I already saw a kind of problem related with my issue like (right namespaces, doctype...) but nothing works for me.

In my pom file, i declared jsf-api:2.0(provided) and primefaces:3.5

my layout.xhtml looks like this :

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
 "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
 <html
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
 xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
 xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
 xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
 xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

 <h:head>
    <title>Title</title>
  </h:head>
  <h:body>
          <p:layout fullPage="true">
        <p:layoutUnit position="north" size="100" header="Top" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
            <h:outputText value="Top unit content." />
          </p:layoutUnit>

          <p:layoutUnit position="south" size="100" header="Bottom" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
              <h:outputText value="South unit content." />
          </p:layoutUnit>

         <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="200" header="Left" resizable="true" closable="true" collapsible="true">
            <h:form>
                <!-- ..... -->
            </h:form>
         </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="east" size="200" header="Right" resizable="true"    closable="true" collapsible="true" effect="drop">
            <h:outputText value="Right unit content." />
        </p:layoutUnit>

        <p:layoutUnit position="center">
            <ui:insert name="content">Put default content here, if any.</ui:insert>
        </p:layoutUnit>
    </p:layout>
</h:body>
```

and the page.xhtml that i display looks like this :

```
  <ui:composition template="/templates/layout.xhtml"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
   xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
   xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
   xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
   xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">      
   <ui:define name="content">
     <h:form>
        <p:commandButton value="View" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
            actionListener="#{dialogBean.viewCars()}" />

        <p:commandButton value="Options" icon="ui-icon-extlink"
            actionListener="#{dialogBean.viewCarsCustomized()}" />
    </h:form>
  </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
```

I have tried all kind of layout in primefaces showcase no one works for me

[enter link description here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutHome.jsf)

thanks for your help

Comment: what are you trying to do ? Displaying the second page in the first one ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a styling issue.
Download this jar from [Primefaces Aristo](http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/aristo/1.0.1/)

and make sure that this is available in applications classpath
and do the changes to web.xml file **don't** specify any context-param for "primefaces.THEME".

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Had similar issue where layouts are rendering in JSF. The solution is in web.xml.

`<welcome-file-list>` in web.xml should be as follows

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

if you just have index.xhtml, layouts will not be rendered

Comment: This is not true. It depends on how you map facelet pages to url... Your answer is only valid in the context of your web.xml. Not a generic answer

Comment: This configuration has nothing to with URL mapping. I still access my app using http://localhost:8080/MyWebApp. my index.xhtml is directly placed inside WEB-INF/

Comment: It depends on how the url mapping of the faces servlet is done…  believe me